# Google Maps with ReactJS not loading

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-react

Please help. I am trying to load a map using my API KEY. 
The problem is that neither map nor props are loading. Probably I'm missing the point.

Any ideas?

Here's the [repo](https://github.com/davide2894/react-neighborhood-map)

And here's the Map Container's code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {GoogleApiWrapper, Map} from 'google-maps-react';

const API_KEY = 'apikeystring';

export class Container extends Component {

    render() {

      const style = {
        width: '200px',
        height: '200px'
      }

      if (!this.props.loaded) {
        return <div>Loading props...</div>
      }

      return (
        <div style={style}>
            <Map 
                google={window.google} 

                initialCenter={{
                    lat: 44.498955,
                    lng: 11.327591
                }}
                style={{
                    width: '100px',
                    height: '100px'
                }}
            />
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

  export default GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: (API_KEY)
  })(Container)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In order to show your Loading props, you have to do it like this:

```
return (
<div style={style}>
{(!this.props.loaded) ? <div>Loading props...</div> : null}
    <Map 
        google={window.google} 

        initialCenter={
            lat: 44.498955,
            lng: 11.327591
        }
        style={{
            width: '100px',
            height: '100px'
        }}
    />
</div>
```

I’m not sure but I don’t think you need double courly braces for initialCenter, hope it helps.